# How to update records based on sum of a field then use the sum to calc a new value in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, sum

Below is what I'm trying to do with by iterating through the records.

I would like to have a more elegant solution if possible since I'm sure this is not the best way to do it in sql.

```
set @counter = 1 

declare @totalhrs dec(9,3), @lastemp char(7), @othrs dec(9,3) 

while @counter <= @maxrecs 
begin 
  if exists(select emp_num from #tt_trans where id = @counter) 
  begin 
    set @nhrs = 0 
    set @othrs = 0 

    select @empnum = emp_num, @nhrs = n_hrs, @othrs = ot_hrs 
    from #tt_trans 
    where id = @counter 

    if @empnum = @lastemp 
    begin 
      set @totalhrs = @totalhrs + @nhrs 

      if @totalhrs > 40 
      begin 
        set @othrs = @othrs + @totalhrs - 40 
        set @nhrs = @nhrs - (@totalhrs - 40) 
        set @totalhrs = 40 
      end 
    end 
    else 
    begin 
       set @totalhrs = @nhrs 
       set @lastemp = @empnum 
    end 

    update #tt_trans 
    set n_hrs = @nhrs, 
        ot_hrs = @othrs 
    where id = @counter and can_have_ot = 1 
  end 

  set @counter = @counter + 1 
end
```

Thx

Comment: Hang on a sec. I think your existing code has some pretty severe logic problems. It looks like you are adding up all the hours for each employee, determining the total OT and Regular hours. Then updating the n_hrs (overwriting it) and the ot_hrs columns of the last record for each employee. 

I can't imagine a situation where ypu'd want to do that. So something is amiss. 

Can you explain in English what you are trying to do? Perhaps giving a before/after example of the contents of the table?

Comment: Basically what I need to do is for all of the employees who have over 40 hours in a period is to adjust their punches to accomodate the fact that they worked overtime. It backs out n_hrs and moves the hours to ot_hrs keeping the total hours the same. The end user should be able to look at which days the ot_hrs (when the broke 40) happen.

Comment: Example before <br>emp# n_hrs ot_hrs date <br>1 8.2 0 1/1 <br>1 8.5 0 1/2 <br>1 8.6 0 1/3 <br>1 8.7 0 1/4 <br>1 8.0 0 1/5 2 10.3 0 1/1 <br>2 10.6 0 1/2 <br>2 12.0 0 1/3 <br>2 10.0 0 1/4 <br>after <br>emp# n_hrs ot_hrs date <br>1 8.2 0 1/1 <br>1 8.5 0 1/2 <br>1 8.6 0 1/3 <br>1 8.7 0 1/4 <br>1 6.0 2.0 1/5 <br>2 10.3 0 1/1 <br>2 10.6 0 1/2 <br>2 12.0 0 1/3 <br>2 7.1 2.9 1/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update #tt_trans
    set n_hrs = case 
    when t2.totHrs > 40
    then n_hrs - (t2.totHrs -40)
    else n_hrs
    end,
    ot_hrs = case 
    when t2.totHrs > 40 
    then ot_hrs + (t2.totHrs -40)
    else ot_hrs
    end
    from #tt_trans t1
    join (select sum (n_hrs) as totHrs, emp_num from #tt_trans where can_have_ot =1 group by emp_num) t2 on t1.emp_num = t2.emp_num where t1.post_date = (select max(post_date)from #tt_trans where emp_num = t1.emp_num)
```

Basically I took the modified the hours of the last date in the period and adjusted accoringly. Thanks to the both of you who responded. Both replies led me to mine.

Answer (score 1):

This is close to what you want, but will need to be tuned a bit once you answer my comment about what you are really trying to achieve.

```
update #tt_trans 
    set n_hrs = CASE WHEN T2.totHrs>40 
                     THEN 40 
                     ELSE T2.totHrs END,
    ot_hrs= CASE WHEN T2.totHrs>40 
                 THEN T2.totHrs-40 
                 ELSE 0 END
FROM  #tt_trans trans T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT SUM(@nhrs) totHrs, EmpNum 
           FROM #tt_trans 
           WHERE can_have_ot=1 
           GROUP BY EmpNum) T2 ON (T1.EmpNum=T2.EmpNum)

WHERE can_have_ot = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are iterating because you have to keep track of the total hours for a given employee across multiple records. You can instead use an interior select to sum the hours for each employee, and join that select to your #tt_trans table. Write your update from that join, and put your logic in CASE statements for the updating columns.